# How to make Ubuntu 10.10 boot faster?

Tags: boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make Ubuntu boot fast?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10290/how-to-make-ubuntu-boot-fast)

hi, i m using Ubuntu 10.10 64bit OS. while booting in a black screen it shows blinking "_" about 10 seconds. how can it be solved?

Comment: The blinking "_" isn't responsible for any slowness; it's just what shows on the screen while the computer is booting if Ubuntu's startup graphics don't work with your graphics card/driver (which seems to be the case for pretty much everybody).

Answer (score -1):

the blinking dash is usually your gui loading.
for any operating system windows ubuntu or otherwise you can go to your startup programs menu and limit the ammount of programs that load at startup and that will definitely speed up your startup. the other option is to turn off your gui and rely on the cli as some users do it would boot alot faster as there are no graphics to load