# How can I improve my start-up time

Tags: startup, optimization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make Ubuntu boot fast?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10290/how-to-make-ubuntu-boot-fast)

Hey, I've loaded Ubuntu on an older laptop and while it loads faster than Windows used to I'd like it to load even faster. Are there any strategies for improving the time from power-on to the login screen?