# How do I speed up boot time?

Tags: boot, startup, plymouth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I improve boot speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10290/how-do-i-improve-boot-speed)

I am dual-booting Ubuntu and Windows 7. When I select Ubuntu at the GRUB menu, a blinking cursor in a black screen comes and takes some 30-40 seconds. Then Ubuntu opens normally and fast. How do I reduce the time the blinking cursor takes (or remove it if possible)?

Comment: I'm sure there's a duplicate of this question somewhere.