# How do I improve boot time?

Tags: boot, performance, startup-applications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I improve boot speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10290/how-do-i-improve-boot-speed)

I Have read many question on this but It is all about disabling startup daemons/programs. Since then I have installed a lot of programs and as you know some programs adds some stuffs to startup.

I need specific help to disable all processes that cannot affect my computer normal operation and start others when needed. Now I need a command to log list of startup app so that I can post them here and you guys can help me what to disable and what to leave.