# Decrease Boot Time

Tags: boot, init

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Improve Boot time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66919/improve-boot-time)

I have an 11.10 system that takes a while to boot. I ran bootchart and it reported that there was a block of time about 10 seconds long where there was no system activity besides init whereas other ubuntu bootcharts that I have seen only have a 1 or 2 second gap. What I want to do is increase my boot speed by decreasing that gap. Any suggestions