# Speed up boot time

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, startup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I improve boot speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10290/how-do-i-improve-boot-speed)

In ubuntu "example" folder, it shows me that Ubuntu is ready to work in just 7 second.

how can I make my ubuntu boot as fast as that video? I tried googling found all around the forum and blog only told me to profiling, add "profile" to grub config file and `concurency=shell` to initrd, remove junks, remove unecessary startup apps(but i have no startup list yet)

I have tried it all but nothing changes.My ubuntu shows my desktop in 32 second, still same.

I have Ubuntu 12.04 on acer aspire4739 x86(32bit)