# decreasing boot time on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, boot, ethernet

I know it is just a luxury problem. But I would like to decrease the boot time of Ubuntu 12.04. Before it started up within 60 seconds, after tweaking a bit I keep it now constantly around 37 seconds.

The last crucial part in my "dmesg" output are the following lines:

> [    5.744117] firewire_core: created device fw0: GUID 0011d8000164b059, S400
>   [   35.289084] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
>   [   35.289091] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready

I do not even have any idea what causes this delay, either this "firewire_core" or "ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP)". **Does anybody know how to fix this issue?**

*Besides, my Internet connection works fine so far. It is just about decreasing the computer's start up.*

Comment: I did two steps to decrease the time for ubuntu's start up.

1. I installed e4rat following this [tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/69753/how-to-cut-your-linux-pcs-boot-time-in-half-with-e4rat/).
2. I disabled one of the Ethernet adapters in BIOS.

Comment: Disabling ethernet checking at boot time is related to this one -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/149514/disable-ethernet-permanently-to-speed-up-boot-time?rq=1 . Decreasing boot time is a duplicate of this one -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/10290/how-do-i-improve-boot-speed