# Ubuntu 12.10 boots slowly

Tags: boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I improve boot speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10290/how-do-i-improve-boot-speed)

I have upgraded ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10 but it boots slowly.
My config: Intel Core i5 2500, Nvidia GTS450, 8GB 1333Mhz RAM, 1TB HDD (5400rpm), Asrock h61m/u3s3. 
Here's the bootchart image: http://postimage.org/image/jr4cy70np/
I think it should boot faster and don't know what the problem can be.

Comment: I have the same problem, it takes 77 seconds an i7 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00GHz, with 12.04 was 61 seconds, that's aprox. 25% slower with new release. The login process, after entering my password also takes more time, I do not have a exact measure for this though, but I can tell that it takes at least 10 seconds to start showing the desktop, with 12.04 it was almost instantanly, less than 2 seconds, I'm sure. I did upgrade mostly because of the Unity preview, I hope the speed issue could be solved.

Comment: Here's my bootchart graphic: http://ubuntuone.com/3GMVoQY1LLtBlBD0cwgU8S