# Start up on Ubuntu 12.10 is much slower than on 12.04

Tags: 12.10, startup

Start up toward login screen lasts about 40sec on both(12.10 and 12.04). This is good for me.

But after login, there is quite difference. System will start up in:

- Ubuntu 12.04: 10-13sec
- Ubuntu 12.10: at least 30sec

I have chromium in start up applications and this is the only non default app there. I also disabled some unneeded apps such as Bluetooth Manager, ... I also have installed preload.

Is there problem on my side or is the new Ubuntu slower in this way?

My PCs info:
Intel® Pentium(R) CPU G840 @ 2.80GHz × 2
GeForce GTS 450/PCIe/SSE2
Memory 3.9 GiB
Ubuntu 12.10 32-bit

Comment: You can find some help here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/10290/how-do-i-improve-boot-speed but remember, you are 12.10, so some stuff there should not be done. I recommend the answer by David Andersson about the boot chart. Might help for a diagnostic.

Comment: I find I have a significantly faster system startup by a fresh install (over upgrading.)

Answer (score 0):

For me it varies.

On some PCs the time is the same, on others the time for 12.10 is slightly faster. On a few, the time difference is noticeable (Like 10 to 15 seconds faster). This changes if I update the system. After upgrading 12.10, the changes is more noticeable for more PCs as 12.10 somehow speeds up.

What I would recommend would be to remove preload, Chromium and any other non-default changes you made. Then test both. Just a FYI, preload sometimes does not make the boot part faster. This varies on the hardware/software.

For 40 seconds of time, I would also suggest for you to add your hardware specs here. This could lead to better help.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I will try to uninstall preload. Anyway, any other issues how to speed up boot would very be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit if your processor is 64-bit architecture. Actually I have a Laptop (Asus) with Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit and it runs faster than Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit.