# Help setting up e4rat, no startup.log after e4rat-collect

Tags: boot, grub2, init

So I've scanned through all the wiki's and posts to no avail. I'm attempting to set up `e4rat` on Ubuntu 12.10, and after appending `init=/sbin/e4rat-collect` to Grub and changing `ro` to `rw` `startup.log` is still failing to appear.

This is the output to `dmesg | grep e4rat`

```
lenny@ubuntu:~$ dmesg | grep e4rat
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-25-generic root=UUID=D018D9CE18D9B426 loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk rw quiet splash init=/sbin/e4rat-collect vt.handoff=7
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-25-generic root=UUID=D018D9CE18D9B426 loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk rw quiet splash init=/sbin/e4rat-collect vt.handoff=7
[   28.777556] e4rat-collect: failsafe main process (955) killed by TERM signal
[   38.227687] e4rat-collect: lightdm main process (1217) killed by TERM signal
```

Anyone think they can help?

Comment: Where did you look for the file? Mine is at `/var/lib/e4rat/startup.log` Maybe it is still collecting the data. Try `sudo e4rat-collect --stop` to make it stop and create the log file.

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem and just solved it (at least for me).
The site [E4rat ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/E4rat) helped.

I edited the /etc/e4rat.conf, set verbose and log level both to 31, uncommented the rest (may not be necessary) and changed the log file path (log_target) to /var/log/e4rat
.

Then I rebooted, set the init=/sbin/e4rat-collect, waited the 120 secs and checked the log file. It turned out, that it couldn't find the file (or folder?) it supposed to create (var/lib/e4rat/startup.log). So I created the folder and the file manually. And after another boot with e4rat-collect it worked.

Hope it helped and wasn't too late :-)