# SLOW Boot and Login times Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04, login, network-manager, lightdm

Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit taking around 20 sec from Login screen to desktop and around 20 seconds from grub to login screen,

tell me which services i can safely disable, i do not use virtualbox and bluetooth frequently, all other things are used like printer, wifi etc.
output of `systemd-analyze`

```
Startup finished in 5.145s (kernel) + 14.138s (userspace) = 19.284s
```

and output of

```
systemd-analyze blame


 5.837s accounts-daemon.service
          5.444s dev-sda6.device
          4.864s grub-common.service
          4.105s lightdm.service
          4.075s ModemManager.service
          4.001s preload.service
          3.844s apparmor.service
          3.566s networking.service
          3.468s apport.service
          3.332s ondemand.service
          3.272s rsyslog.service
          3.269s systemd-logind.service
          3.253s alsa-restore.service
          3.241s gpu-manager.service
          3.226s avahi-daemon.service
          3.185s systemd-user-sessions.service
          3.185s pppd-dns.service
          2.508s NetworkManager.service
          2.003s user@1000.service
          1.640s plymouth-quit-wait.service
          1.245s colord.service
           712ms systemd-update-utmp.service
           687ms systemd-udevd.service
           669ms udisks2.service
           632ms polkitd.service
           602ms brltty.service
           572ms systemd-localed.service
           567ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
           543ms systemd-rfkill.service
           527ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
           519ms thermald.service
           490ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
           464ms systemd-modules-load.service
           454ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
           450ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           428ms systemd-journald.service
           371ms wpa_supplicant.service
           340ms ufw.service
           317ms systemd-random-seed.service
           284ms console-setup.service
           281ms plymouth-start.service
           270ms dev-hugepages.mount
           270ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
           224ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           177ms dev-mqueue.mount
           168ms plymouth-read-write.service
           165ms upower.service
           131ms dns-clean.service
           103ms systemd-sysctl.service
           102ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-8bd6db03\x2da87b\x2d4614\x2d927a\x2dd5916f3
            68ms systemd-hostnamed.service
            49ms systemd-journal-flush.service
            47ms kmod-static-nodes.service
            47ms snapd.socket
            32ms systemd-remount-fs.service
            28ms rc-local.service
            10ms resolvconf.service
            10ms rtkit-daemon.service
             9ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
             6ms ureadahead-stop.service
             4ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount lines 39-61/61 (END)
```

As well as:

```
systemd-analyze critical-chain

the time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @14.124s
└─lightdm.service @10.018s +4.105s
  └─systemd-user-sessions.service @6.731s +3.185s
    └─basic.target @6.625s
      └─sockets.target @6.625s
        └─snapd.socket @6.576s +47ms
          └─sysinit.target @6.574s
            └─swap.target @6.574s
              └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-8bd6db03\x2da87b\x2d4614\x2d927a\x2dd5916f3c
                └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-8bd6db03\x2da87b\x2d4614\x2d927a\x2dd5916f
lines 1-13/13 (END)
```

i am using a HDD with 7200 RPM, i think boot time is okay, but after login screen, i have to pass 20 secs with a blank screen, I have already disabled some startup items like ORCA, BLUETOOTH, backup monitor, accessibility etc, personal file sharing and user folder update etc, still nothing is improving, how to diagnose the culprit and treat it.

Comment: I like 'bootchart' if it comes to analyzing and partly understanding the boot-process.

Comment: i also installed bootchart but how do i create svg from it, for some reason it always throws this error  path '/var/log/bootchart.tgz' does not exist, ignoring.
Parse error: empty state: '/var/log/bootchart.tgz' does not contain a valid bootchart

Comment: Bootchart images should be auto-generated under /var/log/bootchart/hostname-distribution-date.png' and  '.tgz' if i remember right. Could be you need in addition to 'bootchart' the package 'pybootchartgui'

Comment: Both packages are already installed

Comment: My .tgz and .png files are located in '/var/log/bootchart/' not '/var/log/'.

Comment: bootchart is for some reason is not working and i have purged the same, it was causing system slow down and hogging memory, while  ubuntu 14.04 32 Bit , boot to desktop in around 30 sec with much more packages installed on the same machine.

Comment: what's the value of **loader** in `systemd-analyze`

Comment: I don't know if you use `ModemManager` it takes 5 sec , `preload` take 4 sec or more , `NetworkManager` takes 2.5 sec and `apport` 4 sec  if you disable them you will save more than 10 sec.

Comment: `ModemManager` ==> if you using Modem , `Preload` ==> depend on application so it's number not constant , `NetworkManager` ==> for connecting your wifi automatically  and `apport` ==> system notification dialog

Comment: I have the same problem, for me it takes more than 1 min and 30 secs to boot! take a look at this question to know how to fix bootchart: http://askubuntu.com/questions/788849/bootchart-error

Comment: There's a bootchart functionality included into systemd. Simply run `systemd-analyze plot > bootchart.svg` to create a graphical bootchart image and save it to the file `bootchart.svg`. Simply open it with your favourite image viewer.

Comment: Could you pls reboot your system and then use **dmesg** and post the results here

Comment: If someone will answer I will award the bounty.

Comment: This related question has a good accepted answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/762932/how-to-speed-up-boot-time-of-ubuntu-when-you-find-a-possible-cause-in-dmesg-ou

Comment: 16.04 is just slower to boot, period.  I've tried disabling everything I could and started getting problems from stripping everything away, [see my question here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/774954/16-04-slow-boot-no-matter-what-i-remove-or-do-files-for-analysis-provided).  16.04 just has more and does more.  An SSD drive will help a bit, but my solution was to downgrade to 14.04.  My boot is now 5 seconds to desktop on SSD with 14.04.

Comment: If you have a 32-bit OS, that might explain everything. If not, sorry. Some Tips: upgrade your ram; configure your boot options

Comment: Have you tried $echo FRAMEBUFFER=y | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash $sudo update-initramfs -u $sudo update-grub Just take a look at this post.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/362722/how-to-fix-plymouth-splash-screen-in-all-ubuntu-releases

Comment: Try this link:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/760694/really-slow-boot-on-16-04
or:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/35497/how-to-fix-very-slow-ubuntu-booting
 But whatever happens, Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

Try removing some unused dependencies and orphan packages. This will help.
It worked in my case. Run:

```
sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean
```

Also, you can install **Gtkorphan** (`sudo apt-get install gtkorphan`) to remove all orphaned packages and dependencies left behind by other apps.