# How Can I Profile KDE Startup After Login?

Tags: kde, plasma

I am using KDE and the time to desktop after I enter my log in details has been taking progressively longer.

It now takes about 30 seconds to show the desktop after login, however, on initial install it was almost immediate.

Is there a log file with timings that will help me determine what is slowing down the login process?

Comment: Maybe this answer might help:  https://askubuntu.com/a/763070/231142

Comment: That refers to boot time though. This is about the time after Ubuntu has booted and I have logged in and am waiting for the Desktop to appear.

Comment: Look in your Settings -> Session and Startup in the Application Autostart tab and unselect startup items that you feel you might not need at startup.  Over time, some applications will add a startup item to that location that you don't need starting up.  Any of these can affect the time after your login has happened.