# How to speed up Boot Time in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot-time

I am using Ubuntu 18.04

I am confused with `quiet splash` adding `nomodeset` something like this..

What is the best option to boost the boot up time?  My main aim is to reduce the boot time with in the given choices like `quiet splash nomodeset` or if 50 things to add, I am ready to do that if it can reduce the boot time.

i run the command
`sudo journalctl --boot > boot.log` it saved a copy in my home folder.

Here is the link https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/sSV9vhsyKh/

Output of `systemd-analyze blame`
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Bd7wcbX5qF/

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1047887/edit) your question and add the output of `systemd-analyze blame`.

Comment: Add the results of the command yes. It will show what time each process cost when booting. If for instance it takes a bit of time for your wireless to appear it will show that and you could focus on something specific. Oh and `quite`, `splash` and `nomodeset` do NOT shorten boot time.

Comment: Also, it's `quiet`, not `quite`.

Comment: The factors you want to know are in the output of `systemd-analyze blame`. That's why we ask for it.

Comment: If not using snaps, you can remove them also. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039411/how-can-i-replace-snap-application-such-as-gnome-calculator-with-a-deb

Comment: I removed them one by one. The link above shows a command with just each snap in one line.   This shows yours `snap list` & I had to unmount several /snap/core/xxx and stop snap with `sudo systemctl stop snapd` to let me remove core.

Comment: Wait about 10 minutes after boot, and try `systemd-analyze blame` again. If systemd still reports that boot is not finished, then that's a different problem (maybe related, maybe not) that you must search and solve first.

Comment: Why? You have accepted an answer already.

Comment: AskUbuntu is a Question & Answer site. It's not a discussion forum. See the [site tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour). When you accepted an answer, it means you were satisfied with that answer to your question. You were done. There are plenty of places to get *interactive* help, so please use AskUbuntu the way it is intended to be used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Boot time is "controlled" by the speed at which the installed programs and services can load. So to speed it up:

- Have a faster boot disk (using a faster SSD or similar - faster storage to load the programs from). You have this, so....
- *Probably* DON'T need to worry about faster memory, though more of it and using `preload` could help with some programs particularly after boot. 6GB should be enough for now!
- *Removes unnecessary services (or dont install them in the first place)*

The latter is the cheapest, and you already found one of the more ideal solutions in `systemd-analyze` (for newer linux systems). The `blame` option lists the services that take longest to complete (note, ones like `plymouth`, have to wait for other services to finish starting to complete, so removing them wont improve boot time by much).

Some services are important to the systems operation, so aren't ideal to remove (e.g. NetworkManager), but perhaps can be configured so no errors occur or it doesnt try and load stuff you may not use (e.g. `lvm`). If you post the top output of `blame` in your question we may be able to help with this!

Also, running `systemd-analyze plot > file.svg` will give you a visual overview of the boot time (as an image `file.svg`). Other methods are listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10290/how-do-i-improve-boot-speed) (but surprisingly misses the `plot` option covered [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/763070/178596)).

The options you added are explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/716957/what-do-the-nomodeset-quiet-and-splash-kernel-parameters-mean). I'm not sure if I've heard of uses for them outside of dealing with weird video hardware, but any speed increase here is from skipping the splash screen. It might increase speed a bit but the output shows its starting up properly (i.e. I wouldn't bother except on a computer without a display in a fixed state).

Comment: @PRATAP have you changed anything (including those kernel options?). I'm guessing service(s) are failing to start, slowing it down. Can you  append to the question a boot log (under systemd `sudo journalctl --boot > boot.log` (https://paste.ubuntu.com/ if necessary). If you boot it and leave if for a while, `systemd-analyze`may work so you can add the outputs of `blame` or `plot > systemd-plot.svg`. Note in future a minimal install should be leaner on boots times so you dont have to experiment with removing things (removing some stuff may make it slower if it expects it to be there!)

Comment: Hmm it shows `i7-6550U` on the boot log! (You can confirm this with `lscpu` or `lshw`). Do you have a discrete GPU? I guess after the 20-30 second mark you have logged in (automatically?) - you can probably remove [whoopsie](https://askubuntu.com/q/135540/178596), [`spice-vdagent`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/spice-vdagent) & [`xbrlapi.desktop`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/xbrlapi) (if you dont use the latter ones!) to speed up login.

Comment: Also, messing with fsck and `fastboot` can marginally help https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/239709/52956 Setting a fixed IP on the network (and perhaps disabling autoconnecting to it if you dont need it straight away!). The cpu governer also appears to be on powersave BTW (https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/182696/52956). Further optimisation requires working out what is not causing it to finish booting properly (I cant guess at this time!), and getting `systemd-analyze` working :/ Does `sudo systemctl --failed` show anything?