# Which tasks are really needed for a successful boot?

Tags: boot, 18.04, boot-time

From the question [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1047887/891640) I found a way to figure out, what is really time consuming. Output of `systemd-analyze blame`:

```
 15.389s dev-sda5.device
 15.159s snapd.service
 15.133s plymouth-quit-wait.service
 13.330s systemd-journal-flush.service
  8.162s plymouth-start.service
  8.073s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
  7.582s systemd-udevd.service
  7.220s systemd-sysctl.service
  7.158s sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
  7.157s sys-kernel-config.mount
  7.017s snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-51.mount
  6.959s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-70.mount
  6.914s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-180.mount
  6.887s snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-103.mount
  6.827s snap-gnome\x2dlogs-37.mount
  6.752s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-319.mount
  5.594s NetworkManager.service
  5.035s ModemManager.service
  4.721s grub-common.service
  4.621s networkd-dispatcher.service
  3.918s udisks2.service
  3.670s dev-loop6.device
  3.432s dev-loop2.device
  3.299s accounts-daemon.service
  2.778s wpa_supplicant.service
  2.299s dev-loop5.device
  2.219s dev-loop4.device
  2.129s dev-loop3.device
  [< 2s is skipped]
```

But what is really necessary? Sorry - I am new to ubuntu...

Comment: Most things. But I do uninstall snaps and convert to standard app or just not use any default snaps. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039411/how-can-i-replace-snap-application-such-as-gnome-calculator-with-a-deb & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2391341