# Both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 18.04: Random frozen screen

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, system-installation, acpi

I have a [Acer Travelmate 8572G](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/ID/content/support-product/2534;-;) which ran with Windows 7 before.
From time to time it randomly happened, that the screen froze and I had to shut down using the power button.
Now I switched to Ubuntu and it seems, it shows the same behaviour. As I am new to Ubuntu, any help / hint is highly appreciated.

What I did so far:

- Windows: A friend who is a system administrator had a look at it: he could not find anything. Performance, especially boot time was (and is) great.
- Ubuntu: I searched, but could not find anything. According to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/762932/891640), I tried `dmesg`; its output is below.
- Ubuntu: From [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/953666/891640) in combination with my `dmesg` output I guess that I have an ACPI error? Please see 22.824497 seconds into the dmesg output below.

Please let me know, if you need anything else. **I marked the the part where I think the error messages occur**.

Output from `dmesg`

```
...
[    3.220523] acpi PNP0C14:01: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:00)
[    3.323939] intel ips 0000:00:1f.6: CPU TDP doesn't match expected value (found 25, expected 29)
[    3.324993] intel ips 0000:00:1f.6: failed to get i915 symbols, graphics turbo disabled until i915 loads
[    3.327444] intel ips 0000:00:1f.6: IPS driver initialized, MCP temp limit 90
[    3.407857] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[    3.453189] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[    3.609551] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
[    3.690379] wl: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    3.690385] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[    3.690386] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[    3.695116] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    3.695824] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    3.705139] cryptd: max_cpu_qlen set to 1000
[    3.760550] SSE version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[    3.771100] pci 0000:00:00.0: Intel HD Graphics Chipset
[    3.771129] pci 0000:00:00.0: detected gtt size: 2097152K total, 262144K mappable
[    3.771581] pci 0000:00:00.0: detected 131072K stolen memory
[    3.771639] checking generic (d0000000 300000) vs hw (d0000000 10000000)
[    3.771640] fb: switching to inteldrmfb from VESA VGA
[    3.771695] Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25
[    3.771972] [drm] Replacing VGA console driver
[    3.774977] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    3.774979] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    3.776407] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
[    3.816059] [drm] RC6 disabled, disabling runtime PM support
[    3.825911] wlan0: Broadcom BCM4357 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.271 (r587334)

[    3.852606] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20180514 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    3.852933] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[    3.853355] ACPI: Video Device [PEGP] (multi-head: yes  rom: yes  post: no)
[    3.853708] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input13
[    3.855847] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    3.855988] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:02/input/input14
[    3.859285] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device 1.3M WebCam (04f2:b1d8)
[    3.872794] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    3.872913] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 170x48
[    3.872970] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[    3.878900] acer_wmi: Acer Laptop ACPI-WMI Extras
[    3.878949] acer_wmi: Function bitmap for Communication Button: 0x801
[    3.879321] input: Acer WMI hotkeys as /devices/virtual/input/input15
[    3.895243] MXM: GUID detected in BIOS
[    3.896572] uvcvideo 1-1.1:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
[    3.896575] uvcvideo 1-1.1:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 3 was not initialized!
[    3.896577] uvcvideo 1-1.1:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[    3.896680] input: 1.3M WebCam: 1.3M WebCam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/input/input16
[    3.897613] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    3.897615] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[    3.898009] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.GFX0._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20180531/nsarguments-66)
[    3.898073] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0: failed to evaluate _DSM
[    3.898131] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.P0P2.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20180531/nsarguments-66)
[    3.898166] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.P0P2.PEGP: failed to evaluate _DSM
[    3.898174] VGA switcheroo: detected DSM switching method \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0 handle
[    3.898227] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0004 -> 0007)
[    3.909950] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: NVIDIA GT216 (0a5480a2)
[    3.950155] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    4.001666] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0: CX20585: BIOS auto-probing.
[    4.002169] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for CX20585: line_outs=1 (0x1f/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    4.002172] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    4.002174] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x19/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    4.002176] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    4.002177] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    4.002180] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x23
[    4.002182] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x1b
[    4.003293] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0: Enable sync_write for stable communication
[    4.014134] wl 0000:09:00.0 wlp9s0: renamed from wlan0
[    4.027934] input: HDA Intel MID Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input17
[    4.028042] input: HDA Intel MID Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input18
[    4.028675] kvm: VM_EXIT_LOAD_IA32_PERF_GLOBAL_CTRL does not work properly. Using workaround
[    4.441535] acer_wmi: Set Device Status failed: 0xe1 - 0x0
[    4.829508] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[    4.858452] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bios: version 70.16.57.00.07
[    4.903948] acer_wmi: Set Device Status failed: 0xe1 - 0x0
[    4.904948] acer_wmi: Set Device Status failed: 0xe1 - 0x0
[    4.939950] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0489, idProduct=e011, bcdDevice= 8.61
[    4.939954] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    4.939956] usb 1-1.2: Product: Acer Module
[    4.939957] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Broadcom Corp
[    4.939959] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: C44619C300D0
[    4.980230] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.980260] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[    4.980261] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.980267] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.980270] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.980278] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.993249] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[    5.228962] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb: 1024 MiB DDR3
[    5.312519] vga_switcheroo: enabled
[    5.312773] [TTM] Zone  kernel: Available graphics memory: 1852308 kiB
[    5.312776] [TTM] Initializing pool allocator
[    5.312785] [TTM] Initializing DMA pool allocator
[    5.312829] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: VRAM: 1024 MiB
[    5.312831] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: GART: 1048576 MiB
[    5.312838] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: TMDS table version 2.0
[    5.312841] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB version 4.0
[    5.312845] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 00: 01000323 00010034
[    5.312848] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 01: 02011300 00000000
[    5.312851] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 02: 08022382 00020010
[    5.312854] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 00: 00000040
[    5.312857] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 01: 00000100
[    5.312859] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 02: 00001231
[    5.314331] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    5.314332] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    5.316642] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: MM: using COPY for buffer copies
[    5.329342] [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes
[    5.329389] [drm] Initialized nouveau 1.3.1 20120801 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
[    5.643527] audit: type=1400 audit(1572891771.341:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-oopslash" pid=744 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    5.644378] audit: type=1400 audit(1572891771.345:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/man" pid=743 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    5.644382] audit: type=1400 audit(1572891771.345:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_filter" pid=743 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    5.644385] audit: type=1400 audit(1572891771.345:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_groff" pid=743 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    5.646279] audit: type=1400 audit(1572891771.345:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-senddoc" pid=745 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    5.649118] audit: type=1400 audit(1572891771.349:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-xpdfimport" pid=747 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    5.650343] audit: type=1400 audit(1572891771.349:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=740 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    5.650349] audit: type=1400 audit(1572891771.349:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=740 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    5.650352] audit: type=1400 audit(1572891771.349:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=740 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    5.650355] audit: type=1400 audit(1572891771.349:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=740 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    6.049580] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.049582] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.049588] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    6.784332] acer_wmi: Set Device Status failed: 0xe1 - 0x0
[    6.868584] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[    7.649860] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[    7.650374] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link is down
[    7.655387] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp9s0: link is not ready
[    7.773579] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp9s0: link is not ready
[    8.587261] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp9s0: link becomes ready
[    8.644167] intel ips 0000:00:1f.6: i915 driver attached, reenabling gpu turbo
[   15.339495] [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes
[   21.429677] random: crng init done
[   21.429683] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
[   22.044286] systemd-journald[284]: File /var/log/journal/b1646eb850b94782bceafaf807262c01/user-1000.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
[   22.824086] calling mux switch 16
[   22.824269] mux mutex set switched 0
[   22.824270] calling mux switch 16
[   22.824372] mux switched 0

#####################################################
# I guess, the error occurs here for the first time #
#####################################################

[   22.824497] ACPI Error: Needed [Buffer/String/Package], found [Integer] 00000000d30f9b04 (20180531/exresop-560)
[   22.824508] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Index] (20180531/dswexec-427)
[   22.824519] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [_DSM]:
[   22.824520]   Local0: 000000000780b2c6 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000002
[   22.824531] Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
[   22.824532]   Arg0:   0000000083736f51 <Obj>           Buffer(16) A0 A0 95 9D 60 00 48 4D
[   22.824545]   Arg1:   00000000c1efc734 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
[   22.824551]   Arg2:   00000000c6f9db73 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000002
[   22.824557]   Arg3:   00000000d30f9b04 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000011
[   22.824593] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.GFX0._DSM, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20180531/psparse-516)
[   22.824630] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0: failed to evaluate _DSM (0x3003)
[   22.824633] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0: failed to evaluate _DSM
[   22.824868] ACPI Error: Needed [Buffer/String/Package], found [Integer] 0000000083736f51 (20180531/exresop-560)
[   22.824879] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Index] (20180531/dswexec-427)
[   22.824921] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [_DSM]:
[   22.824923]   Local0: 0000000058fe9de2 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000003
[   22.824939] Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
[   22.824943]   Arg0:   00000000d30f9b04 <Obj>           Buffer(16) A0 A0 95 9D 60 00 48 4D
[   22.824970]   Arg1:   00000000c6f9db73 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
[   22.824992]   Arg2:   00000000c1efc734 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000003
[   22.825005]   Arg3:   0000000083736f51 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000002
[   22.825036] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.GFX0._DSM, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20180531/psparse-516)
[   22.825100] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0: failed to evaluate _DSM (0x3003)
[   22.825105] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0: failed to evaluate _DSM
[   22.826589] ACPI Error: Needed [Buffer/String/Package], found [Integer] 0000000057f04209 (20180531/exresop-560)
[   22.826602] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Index] (20180531/dswexec-427)
[   22.826616] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [_DSM]:
[   22.826618]   Local0: 00000000e974a610 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000003
[   22.826628] Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
[   22.826629]   Arg0:   0000000012f5820b <Obj>           Buffer(16) A0 A0 95 9D 60 00 48 4D
[   22.826646]   Arg1:   000000000f466259 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
[   22.826653]   Arg2:   0000000005330fde <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000003
[   22.826661]   Arg3:   0000000057f04209 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000001
[   22.826673] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.GFX0._DSM, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20180531/psparse-516)
[   22.826697] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0: failed to evaluate _DSM (0x3003)
[   22.826699] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0: failed to evaluate _DSM
[   26.142654] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   26.142668] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   26.142678] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   27.863669] rfkill: input handler disabled
[   33.200097] calling mux switch 16
[   33.200343] mux mutex set switched 0
[   33.200345] calling mux switch 16
[   33.200509] mux switched 0
[   33.200705] ACPI Error: Needed [Buffer/String/Package], found [Integer] 0000000059808404 (20180531/exresop-560)
[   33.200720] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Index] (20180531/dswexec-427)
[   33.200736] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [_DSM]:
[   33.200738]   Local0: 000000006ceea97c <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000002
[   33.200752] Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
[   33.200753]   Arg0:   0000000085ac64b1 <Obj>           Buffer(16) A0 A0 95 9D 60 00 48 4D
[   33.200773]   Arg1:   000000008e6a5056 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
[   33.200783]   Arg2:   000000003ee2fd50 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000002
[   33.200791]   Arg3:   0000000059808404 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000011
[   33.200808] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.GFX0._DSM, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20180531/psparse-516)
[   33.200835] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0: failed to evaluate _DSM (0x3003)
[   33.200838] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0: failed to evaluate _DSM
[   33.201033] ACPI Error: Needed [Buffer/String/Package], found [Integer] 0000000085ac64b1 (20180531/exresop-560)
[   33.201045] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Index] (20180531/dswexec-427)
[   33.201059] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [_DSM]:
[   33.201061]   Local0: 00000000c68c3a43 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000003
[   33.201073] Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
[   33.201074]   Arg0:   0000000059808404 <Obj>           Buffer(16) A0 A0 95 9D 60 00 48 4D
[   33.201094]   Arg1:   000000003ee2fd50 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
[   33.201103]   Arg2:   000000008e6a5056 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000003
[   33.201111]   Arg3:   0000000085ac64b1 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000002
[   33.201128] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.GFX0._DSM, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20180531/psparse-516)
[   33.201152] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0: failed to evaluate _DSM (0x3003)
[   33.201155] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0: failed to evaluate _DSM
[   33.201429] ACPI Error: Needed [Buffer/String/Package], found [Integer] 0000000083736f51 (20180531/exresop-560)
[   33.201442] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Index] (20180531/dswexec-427)
[   33.201455] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [_DSM]:
[   33.201457]   Local0: 000000003c29275f <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000003
[   33.201467] Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
[   33.201469]   Arg0:   00000000c1efc734 <Obj>           Buffer(16) A0 A0 95 9D 60 00 48 4D
[   33.201485]   Arg1:   00000000c6f9db73 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
[   33.201492]   Arg2:   00000000d30f9b04 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000003
[   33.201500]   Arg3:   0000000083736f51 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000001
[   33.201513] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.GFX0._DSM, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20180531/psparse-516)
[   33.201536] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0: failed to evaluate _DSM (0x3003)
[   33.201538] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0: failed to evaluate _DSM
[   41.224500] calling mux switch 16
[   41.224709] mux mutex set switched 0
[   41.224711] calling mux switch 16
[   41.224833] mux switched 0
[   41.224981] ACPI Error: Needed [Buffer/String/Package], found [Integer] 000000006ceea97c (20180531/exresop-560)
[   41.224995] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Index] (20180531/dswexec-427)
[   41.225008] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [_DSM]:
[   41.225010]   Local0: 0000000006bf947e <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000002
[   41.225021] Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
[   41.225022]   Arg0:   000000003ee2fd50 <Obj>           Buffer(16) A0 A0 95 9D 60 00 48 4D
[   41.225039]   Arg1:   000000008e6a5056 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
[   41.225046]   Arg2:   0000000085ac64b1 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000002
[   41.225053]   Arg3:   000000006ceea97c <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000011
[   41.225066] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.GFX0._DSM, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20180531/psparse-516)
[   41.225088] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0: failed to evaluate _DSM (0x3003)
[   41.225091] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0: failed to evaluate _DSM
[   41.225297] ACPI Error: Needed [Buffer/String/Package], found [Integer] 000000003ee2fd50 (20180531/exresop-560)
[   41.225306] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Index] (20180531/dswexec-427)
[   41.225317] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [_DSM]:
[   41.225318]   Local0: 0000000059808404 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000003
[   41.225328] Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
[   41.225330]   Arg0:   000000006ceea97c <Obj>           Buffer(16) A0 A0 95 9D 60 00 48 4D
[   41.225346]   Arg1:   0000000085ac64b1 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
[   41.225353]   Arg2:   000000008e6a5056 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000003
[   41.225360]   Arg3:   000000003ee2fd50 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000002
[   41.225372] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.GFX0._DSM, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20180531/psparse-516)
[   41.225392] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0: failed to evaluate _DSM (0x3003)
[   41.225394] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0: failed to evaluate _DSM
```

Comment: If a problem happens with both Windows and Ubuntu, it is a hardware problem. Please remove and re-insert your memory modules.

Comment: @K7AAY I removed and re-inserted RAM and SSD. I hope, that solves the problem. If the problem persists: do you have another idea? Is there any possibility to trace the error?

Comment: I've found sometimes reinstalling Ubuntu results in a stable installation when the first install fails. Perhaps Ubuntu leaves a trail of bread crumbs somewhere in the drive or BIOS which it can use on subsequent installs to find where it went astray? I know Windows 10 does that. As to tracing it, I do not have the skill level to do that in the time I have.

Comment: @K7AAY Ok, thanks! The last 24 hours were fine...

Answer (score 1):

If a problem happens with both Windows and Ubuntu, it is a hardware problem. Please remove and re-insert your memory modules and SSD, following the [manual's instructions](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/ID/content/support-product/2534).

I've also found sometimes reinstalling Ubuntu results in a stable installation when the first install fails. Perhaps Ubuntu leaves a trail of bread crumbs somewhere in the drive or BIOS which it can use on subsequent installs to find where it went astray? I know Windows 10 does that.

As to tracing it from the log file you so usefully provided, I do not have the skill level to do that in the time I have.