# Killing processes for fast startup

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu

Output of `sudo bum`:

[image: Output of sudo bum]

Which of the above processes can I kill for fast startup of my Kubuntu 16.04?

Comment: This question has some good solutions http://askubuntu.com/questions/10290/how-do-i-improve-boot-speed/ and yes, `bum` doesn't work in 16.04 well

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My question is which of these services are safe to disable. The answer you mentioned doesn't state that.

Comment: You first need to identify time eating services, then check what other services depends on it, if critical services depend on that, you have no option, if not you can then disable that service to reduce boot time. There was an answer written by me, which worked for me on 16.04. You can follow it to see if that works.

Comment: @Anwar can you link your answer.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/808934/61218 here

Comment: @Anwar Hi, I tried it but it doesn't work http://askubuntu.com/questions/815488/stopping-start-up-services

Comment: question: does this not depend on what you do with your system? If you have a printer ... cups is needed. Oh and stopping those will NOT lead to a faster boot. Those processes are not started in sequence but parallel. Create a bootchart from your system. That will give more clues to what is taking up boot time. And the only quick gain you get from using ssd as boot.

Answer (score -1):

Killing processes for faster start up of Kubuntu is not good idea...there are another ways to speed things up.

From http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-ways-to-make-linux-boot-faster/:

> ## 1: Disable unnecessary services. Depending upon the use of the machine, plenty of services won't be needed. Using Linux just for a
>
> desktop? Then you won't need sendmail, httpd, and many other services.
>
> ## 2: Disable unnecessary kernel modules If your desktop is wired to the Ethernet, you don't need to have a wireless kernel module loaded. This
>
> task is a bit more difficult and will require a kernel recompilation,
> which is not the easiest task to undertake. To do this, you will need
> the kernel sources. Then, follow the standard steps for compiling a
> kernel. The difference is that you're going to go through your system
> and disable all of the modules you don't need.
>
> ## 3: Use a lightweight window manager instead of GNOME or KDE I plug smaller footprint window managers for a reason — they drastically
>
> reduce graphical boot time. Instead of having to wait that extra 30 to
> 60 seconds for GNOME or KDE to boot up, why not wait two to 10 seconds
> for Enlightenment or XFCE to boot up? Not only will they save you boot
> time, they will save your memory and the headache of dealing with
> bloatware.
>
> ## 4: Use a text-based login instead of a graphical login Most of my Linux machines boot to run level 3 instead of run level 5. This will
>
> halt at the text-based login, where I only have to log in and issue
> startx to start my desktop of choice. The graphical logins do two
> things: increase load times and create headaches trying to recover
> from an X windows fubar.

Comment: This is a word-to-word copy from a blog. Care to mention the reference?

Comment: Plagiarism is not cool. When you copy the work of others, you must always put it in quotes and give a reference.