# Stopping start-up services

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, bluetooth, postgresql

```
 ~  systemd-analyze blame                         
         19.573s dev-sda6.device
         14.841s postgresql@9.5-main.service
         10.254s systemd-udevd.service
          7.085s ModemManager.service
          6.897s NetworkManager.service
          6.215s accounts-daemon.service
          5.375s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
          4.170s grub-common.service
          3.107s gpu-manager.service
          2.560s thermald.service
          2.434s preload.service
          2.375s iio-sensor-proxy.service
          2.155s colord.service
          2.076s rsyslog.service
          1.626s polkitd.service
          1.551s keyboard-setup.service
          1.384s apport.service
          1.364s wpa_supplicant.service
          1.351s systemd-modules-load.service
          1.311s bluetooth.service
          1.284s quota.service
          1.236s systemd-rfkill.service
           965ms avahi-daemon.service
           915ms resolvconf.service
           854ms dev-mqueue.mount
           853ms dev-hugepages.mount
           852ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
           827ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-CA5D\x2dF91D.service
           797ms systemd-journald.service
```

I want to disable to bluetooth and postgresql@9.5-main.service, but I am unable to as below:

```
 ~  sudo systemctl disable bluetooth.service --now
Synchronizing state of bluetooth.service with SysV init with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install...
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install disable bluetooth
insserv: warning: script 'S80panasoniclpd-init' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `bluetooth' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `bluetooth' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
insserv: warning: script 'panasoniclpd-init' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop at service panasoniclpd-init if started
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv: There is a loop between service panasoniclpd-init and mountkernfs if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountkernfs at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop at service plymouth if started
insserv:  loop involving service panasoniclpd-init at depth 1
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
```

Comment: Editing the original question with what you tried would be better than creating new one. That way we can the problem better.

Comment: Seems that this issue is similar to http://askubuntu.com/q/844108/63516.

Answer (score 1):

Try pasting LSB comments in your `/etc/init.d/panasoniclpd-init` :

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          panasoniclpd-init
# Required-Start:    $syslog 
# Required-Stop:     $syslog 
# Should-Start:      panasoniclpd-init
# Should-Stop:       panasoniclpd-init
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: panasoniclpd-init - panasonic
# Description: This daemon for panasonic
### END INIT INFO
```

At the start, just after the shebang (`#!/bin/sh`) line.