# dpkg: error processing package unattended-upgrades

Tags: apt, dpkg, plymouth

On doing sudo apt -f install

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up unattended-upgrades (0.90ubuntu0.1) ...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
insserv: warning: script 'S80panasoniclpd-init' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'panasoniclpd-init' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 3
insserv: There is a loop between service panasoniclpd-init and udev if started
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop at service plymouth if started
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting panasoniclpd-init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv:  loop involving service hddtemp at depth 2
insserv: There is a loop between service panasoniclpd-init and mountkernfs if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountkernfs at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop at service panasoniclpd-init if started
insserv:  loop involving service panasoniclpd-init at depth 1
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package unattended-upgrades (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 unattended-upgrades
```

Getting same with sudo dpkg —configure -a

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem also.
I was able to fix it by adding the following lines to your `/etc/init.d/panasoniclpd-init` file.

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          PanasonicMFSlpd
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: Panasonic scanner driver
# Description:       Panasonic scanner driver
### END INIT INFO
```

It should look like this.

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          PanasonicMFSlpd
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: Panasonic scanner driver
# Description:       Panasonic scanner driver
### END INIT INFO

start() {
        /usr/local/share/panasonic/scanner/bin/PanasonicMFSlpd &
}

stop() {
        killall PanasonicMFSlpd
        echo
}

restart() {
        stop
        start
}

case "$1" in
  start)
        start
        ;;
  stop)
        stop
        ;;
  restart|force-reload)
        restart
        ;;
  *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart|reload|force-reload|condrestart}"
        exit 1
esac

exit 0
```