# Apt-get operations fails with huge error message

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, error-handling

Am not able to install any packages or do any operation with apt-get command.

I tried fixing it with the following commands found in another question here.

```
 sudo apt-get autoremove 
 sudo apt-get --purge remove && sudo apt-get
 autoclean sudo apt-get -f install 
 sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
```

However, i got same error again at the command `sudo apt-get --purge remove && sudo apt-get`

The error is given below.

```
 Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
 state information... Done      The following packages were automatically
 installed and are no longer required:   linux-headers-4.8.0-36
 linux-headers-4.8.0-36-generic linux-headers-4.8.0-41
 linux-headers-4.8.0-41-generic   linux-headers-4.8.0-45
 linux-headers-4.8.0-45-generic linux-headers-4.8.0-46
 linux-headers-4.8.0-46-generic   linux-image-4.8.0-36-generic
 linux-image-4.8.0-41-generic linux-image-4.8.0-45-generic  
 linux-image-4.8.0-46-generic linux-image-extra-4.8.0-36-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.8.0-41-generic  
 linux-image-extra-4.8.0-45-generic linux-image-extra-4.8.0-46-generic
 linux-signed-image-4.8.0-41-generic  
 linux-signed-image-4.8.0-45-generic
 linux-signed-image-4.8.0-46-generic Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to
 remove them. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 112 not
 upgraded. 19 not fully installed or removed. After this operation, 0 
 of additional disk space will be used. Setting up apache2
 (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.2) ... insserv: warning: script
 'S99panasoniclpd-init' missing LSB tags and overrides insserv:
 warning: script 'panasoniclpd-init' missing LSB tags and overrides
```

**Trimmed the error message leaving the last few lines below as character limit reached, the error message is really really huge. Am adding the full error in a gist and [linking here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9e4f36e3ddaa1e9458d7159c288a2969).**

```
 Errors were encountered while processing:  apache2  lightdm  mysql-server-5.7
 binfmt-support  wine1.6  wine1.6-i386:i386  grub-common  grub2-common 
 grub-efi-amd64-bin  grub-efi-amd64  resolvconf  grub-efi-amd64-signed 
 mysql-server  shim-signed  thermald  virtualbox  virtualbox-qt  wine 
 wine1.6-amd64 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please see the full error in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9e4f36e3ddaa1e9458d7159c288a2969).

Comment: Please remove the `>` symbol from start of the output lines. Just paste verbatim output by copy paste.

Comment: Possibly related [dpkg: error processing package unattended-upgrades](https://askubuntu.com/questions/844108/dpkg-error-processing-package-unattended-upgrades)

Answer (score 1):

Panasonic driver was creating the issue. I didn't understand how but. What I did was delete, all instances of the below two folders from all places by searching for it.

1. panasoniclpd-init
2. plymouth

I deleted it from `/etc/int.d/` first and then recursively searched for all other instances and deleted those too. After it i rebooted, and all was fixed.

Comment: It's best to remove software using the same method you installed it. This method probably broke your 'plymouth' package...but you may not discover the damage until your system crashes or the package tries to get updated. A less intrusive way to fix 'insserv' errors is to merely tweak the init file headers to eliminate the logic loop. Afterward, of course, you should file a bug report (with solution) to whoever provided the broken Panasonic software to you.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I don't remember how it was installed. Tried removing with apt-get. Then finally did what I did.