# Hardware Health Monitoring

Tags: 18.04, package-management, hardware, monitoring

I have a Ubuntu server (18.04 LTS) that uses Nginx. I am Trying to find a good package that can monitor hardware health such as

- S.M.A.R.T Checks on HDDS
- CPU and memory utilization (Nginx has Amplify for this already but is not 100%) - not major as i know a million things for this already
- Sensor data (temps, fans, power, failure sensors and so on)
- Any alarms the server alerts that i forgot to mention like doors opened and so on

Things along those lines. I have tried a few like monitorix, nagios and netdata, so on.. but they aren't really filling in the gap so to speak. Monitorix caused some weird issues with other applications because it wanted postfix and some smartutils app so i wrote it off, Nagios i could not get to work with Nginx for love nor money and Netdata although very good did not provide the details i am after

A webui would be nice and beneficial but i don't really care, so long as i can enable reporting/alerting via email or something along those lines, works for what i need.

I only need it because it is a dedicated server in a datacenter and i have to be on my toes with hardware faults as it is not checked for me.

Any suggestions?

## THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

Comment: the smartctl command line utility can give the SMART disk stats. you could couple that with a cron job, or parse output for the emergence of errors, or pre fail conditions via a bash script. `sudo smartctl --all /dev/sda > diskStatus.txt`

Comment: That sounds like it could well work not going to lie. Didn't actually think of a (dare I say before I try) simpler approach such as using a cron job.   What about for other things like sensors?

Comment: Have you looked into webmin?  https://askubuntu.com/a/819665/231142

Comment: So i went for webmin which seems to work okay for what i need. It provides SMART tests which are most important. The sensors i suppose i can work without for now or figure out an alternative way around it. Cheers for your help buddy, appreciate it

Comment: In the Webmin Configuration under Webmin Modules you can install the Status Module from `Standard module from www.webmin.com` and just typing in `status`.  Then in Others you should find `System and Server status` and you can install the LM Sensor Status that will allow you to get emails, etc for the fans, temps, etc.  Make sure that `lm_sensors` is installed on the system you are monitoring.

Comment: Yeah i found that part shortly after writing my last comment. Normally pays to look into things before i start typing.... Once again thank you for your help on this