# long boot times, home folder isn't encrypted

Tags: boot

it boots for like 3-5 minutes, home folder is not encrypted.
is there a way to fix this? if so how? running Ubuntu 17.__ (same problem was on 16lts.

Comment: Has it always taken this long to boot, with the exact same system & hardware? Or is this a new change, and what happened just before it started, and can you reverse that change?

Comment: yes it has always been the case, but booting from usb is significantly faster than booting from the hard drive.

Comment: The faster USB must be a live USB... I'm not sure how they differ exactly, but I'm pretty sure there are utilities to see how much time things take when booting, you could check if something in particular takes a very long time. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/10290/how-do-i-improve-boot-speed (I think your Q might be a duplicate of it, many others have been marked as such)