# How do I reduce time to boot?

Tags: boot

This is my boot time:

```
Startup finished in 2ms (firmware) + 5ms (loader) + 4.414s (kernel) + 1min 13.694s (userspace) = 1min 18.116s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 13.617s in userspace
```

Result of system blame:

```
30.765s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                             >
18.802s dev-sda3.device                                                        >
17.134s snapd.service                                                          >
15.556s networkd-dispatcher.service                                            >
13.260s udisks2.service                                                        >
12.570s accounts-daemon.service                                                >
12.097s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                                     >
10.391s klnagent64.service                                                     >
 9.613s polkit.service                                                         >
 9.596s systemd-journal-flush.service                                          >
 8.729s NetworkManager.service                                                 >
 8.672s avahi-daemon.service                                                   >
 8.669s bluetooth.service                                                      >
 8.442s dev-loop4.device                                                       >
 8.147s dev-loop2.device                                                       >
 7.805s plymouth-read-write.service                                            >
 7.658s switcheroo-control.service                                             >
 7.569s thermald.service                                                       >
 7.567s systemd-logind.service                                                 >
 7.564s wpa_supplicant.service                                                 >
 7.218s dev-loop1.device                                                       >
 7.158s dev-loop5.device                                                       >
 7.068s dev-loop3.device
```

System Specifications:

```
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
CPU(s):                          4
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-3
Thread(s) per core:              2
Core(s) per socket:              2
Socket(s):                       1
Model name:                      Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3110M CPU @ 2.40GHz
```

Which services are fine to disable to reduce boot time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I improve boot speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10290/how-do-i-improve-boot-speed)

Comment: it gives me an idea on how to check the system but what I want is to know which services specifically are ok to disable? I'm still new to Linux and I worry that I might disable some services that can ruin my system

Comment: Next issue: `10.391s klnagent64.service`. It took only a moment for me to learn what this was from Google. You should figure out what it is, and decide if you really want it. It's the biggest non-essential service in your list.