# Lots of time taken to boot my Linux machine

Tags: 20.04, lts

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS and it takes more than 2.5 minutes to boot the machine. Every time I power on the machine, I get the following error
[image]
Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: As you can see from the image: those messages take 0.659 - 0.356 so roughly 0.3 of a second. Those notice have already been answered quite a few times and are benign (those are for kernel developers to address) And regarding a slow boot `systemd-analyze blame` is the tool to use. Please see where the 2m5 comes from, search that service and see if you should disable it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I improve boot speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10290/how-do-i-improve-boot-speed)